# where to save user roles and permissions for whole website access?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, cookies

i am working on user roles and permissions in my website. i want to ask when i fetch user roles and permission which is the best place to store user roles and permissions sessions or Cookies. in my website there are number of users approximately 3000 to 5000. please guide me
 thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User roleas are basically stored in the database. The most common examples of schema:

```
User (UserID, Login, RoleID) -> Role (RoleID, RoleName) - one role for user

User (UserID, Login) -> UserRole (UserID, RoleID) <- Role (RoleID, Name) - many roles for user
```

When user is logged in, you can store roles information in session or request them from the database where it is necessary

Answer (score 1):

Persistence store for Users Information like roles etc should be Database (either SQL or NoSQL, anything would work). But to give seamless experience by not prompting login page for every page request, You should use Session object.

Then comes cookie, so not page is rendered on the client browser, then how would you keep track of user in between these requests, for that use Cookie. So Cookie + Session + Database would give right experience. You can go for CookieLess session in which Session identifier will be passed in URL from client side to server, which sometime no preferable for having user friendly URLs.

so things to keep in mind while using Session is to think of WebFarm scenario, in those cases you need to use Sticky Session or Sessions which are maintained in central store like again databases. No sensitive information needs to be included in the cookie for security reasons, if sensitive information is included them proper encryption needs to be done.